# facebook open graph map layout

Tags: facebook, dictionary, facebook-opengraph, routes

hy,

i have a question regarding the map layout in open graph posts when displaying a route of geopoints. there are the 3 number fields that can be used to display some data about the route, for example distance or time.

so when i create such a route post, i can use a maximum of 3 fields (in my case distance, time and avg. speed)

but when i share running activities from other services they can use 4 fields above the route and the layout looks better.

how can they display 4 values when in the open graph section of the app there are only 3 fields present? and also the docs say:

"Numbers: 
There are three rows of number fields that can be added which are intended to present info about the action that took place..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research i've stumbled upon the answer for my problem:

facebook calls such things "fitness actions", and courses created as such actions have a more decent layout and allow 4 fields to display your metrics.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness

the question that's still left is: can i (or: is it a good idea to) use such fitness actions to create "non fitness" stuff, for example if i want to record and share my route driven with my motorcycle or car?